# Is there an authoritative source for ex-dividend dates?

Tags: ex-dividend-date

I'm looking for a place where I can get ex-dividend dates, and it won't be wrong. For example, this press release announced an ex-dividend date but also had a disclaimer. In this particular case, the disclaimer did apply, and the actual ex-dividend date was not the date in the press release. Some secondary services picked up the ex-dividend date and said it was "not guaranteed to be accurate", which in fact it was not.

[Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/news/whiting-usa-trust-ii-announces-211500272.html)

Answer (score 4):

A dividend is a corporate event where a company's board of directors decides to pay a dividend. It determines the amount, sets a record date and a payment date. The declaration date is when these decisions are announced.  Once done, this is pretty much set in stone.  It's the secondary sources reporting such  information that get it wrong.

There are many dividend calendars available on the internet.  I use the one at the [NASDAQ](https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/dividends) and I have never had any issues with it.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the source one could have the most faith in would be each security's own 'Investor Relations' page. For example: https://investor.apple.com/dividend-history/default.aspx

That said, I would be willing to bet that there is still a disclaimer somewhere on that page that would prevent you from successfully suing them if the information posted there is wrong. And, let's face it, the person typing up the press release about the dividend announcement is probably not the same person filing the paperwork with the markets about said dividends, so mistakes can and do happen.

I like Bob's suggestion of using the NASDAQ page to collect information about more than just 1 security at a time, and have used it myself, also with no grossly wrong information that I recall seeing. +1 to his answer, too.